# How to import custom framework in projects?

Tags: objective-c

I'm a novice in this field, so my question may seem a bit foolish :( I've developed a custom framework which I want to import in other different projects. But when I import that framework into my project that always throws error (say framework name is example1.framework)  file not found. Can anybody tell me how to do it? I added the framework from the build phase of my project's target. What other steps I need to do?

Comment: Can you post the full error message you get?

Comment: http://intridea.com/blog/2010/12/28/a-visual-guide-to-creating-an-embeddable-framework-for-mac-osx

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing a framework you have to add it in your project file.

1. Go to you main project file (the root of your project)
2. Go to tab "Build Phases"
3. Open the section "Link Binary With Libraries"
4. Now add the framework to the project

Last but not the least: build and run your app :].